# How should *intranet* REST API calls be secured?

Tags: security, rest, ssl, certificate

Here's the scenario. A user outside the firewall takes a UI action in the browser. The browser makes a REST API call to system A (and is authenticated and authorized at or near the point of entry past the firewall). System A (inside the corporate network firewall) makes a REST API call to system B (also inside the corporate network firewall).

How much security is sufficient for the "internal" REST API call from system A to system B, considering that authentication and authorization already occurred at the entry point to system A?

Comment: Are you just asking for how to authenticate REST calls?

Comment: By "Securing" do you mean "Validating credentials/knowing who the user is and determining authorization", or do you mean "protecting it from sniffers so that people can't read the data in transit"?  (Or something else entirely)

Comment: @user2246674 -  "best practice" simply means [established best practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice) - it's not best as in "who's the best football team" (which would be a relative/opinion/based term) it's "Best Practice" as in "What are the OWASP-recommended Best Practices for authentication. (Not relative, not opinion-based, rather established and agreed-upon)

Comment: This question is too broad, you don't mention in what way the requirements for "security" between A and B differ from requests that are being made from the "outside world"

Comment: @Taylor My query is specific to the intranet context. So, various methods might be used to secure the initial call to system A. But what method, if any, should we use to secure the call from system A to system B. Since it is an internal call, how much security is good enough?

Comment: @DavidStratton We definitely need to know the user ID. But that can be passed in variously and does not really constitute authentication or authorization per se. My question is, how critical is it to validate that the call to system B came from a trusted source (i.e. system A)? And, if it is important, what are the methods available to me?

Comment: @user2246674 I need to implement the solution in Java. But, fair enough. Most solution approaches probably have corresponding Java implementations.

Comment: @PuneetLamba this is entirely dependent on your requirements and situation.  Many organizations will require nothing, others will require encryption in transmission and authentication with AD/LDAP.

Comment: @alfasin I hope my comments above have helped. Assuming that the initial call in to system A has been adequately authenticated and authorized, what security, if any, would you recommend for the "internal" call from system A to system B?

Comment: Your question is like asking which car you should use on the next race.  Any choice that you'll make might be good or bad, it depends on many other factors which are called requirements. for example, if system B is reachable from the outside and there's a chance that someone malicious will send a "fake" request to B that'll look like as if it was sent from A, then you need to implement every security measure. But what's really sounds weird to me is this: you already have A doing everything properly including all the security checks - why not use the same mechanism in B ?

Comment: @alfasin System B is not reachable from "outside". It is intended for internal use only. All calls to it will come via system A. Therefore, my question is this: once system A has been sufficiently secured, how much security is good enough for the "internal" call from system A to system B? Is IP address mapping good enough?

Comment: @PuneetLamba for *me* it's good enough :) is it "good enough" for you ?  for your company ? who decides what's "good enough" ? good enough for what ? what are the requirements ? are there any requirements at all ?

Comment: @alfasin The requirement is to "prevent" (at what cost?) unauthorized access to system B. But this is not a waterfall project with requirements carved in stone. Requirements (and decisions) are informed by implementation options and cost/benefit ratios.

Comment: Like I said, you already got a fully secured impl. deployed on system A - why not deploy the same one to system B ? why developing another, less secure, system for B ?

Comment: @alfasin This is my final comment on this extended discussion. The current implementation (SSL etc) is for external users and occurs upstream from system A (in the web server and app server). Extending the "same" approach to internal calls between subsystems is neither practical nor free and needs to be considered carefully based on cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: @PuneetLamba these are things you should mention in your question. It's totally not obvious. Why isn't it "free" ? does it cost you money ? why isn't it practical ? isn't it a deploy of the same code on another machine ? these questions might seem obvious to you - but for someone that doesn't know your platform it's not clear.

Comment: A similar question was asked here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468223/what-is-the-best-way-to-secure-soap-web-service-on-an-internal-private-network

Answer (score 7):

Like anything else, it depends on the sensitivity of the data involved, and the level of risk vs. how much the organization wants to spend.

Usually, using strongish SSL (https connection) is considered good enough.  You may need to include an authentication mechanism, if you need to audit which `System A` submitted the request -- for this you could use any of: client cert, HTTP Auth (basic or digest), username/password as request parameters, IP-address mapping, API keys etc.

For system->system calls, if the client system doesn't change (i.e. not a web browser or actively changing clientbase), you don't even need "real" certificates -- a strong self signed certificate is good enough, and because you distribute it to your client systems, they all know the source is valid without a 3rd party signature.

If the data are very sensitive, you might dedicate connections between the client(s) and server, either using a physically separated network, or VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am somewhat familiar with these options. IP address mapping sounds like the simplest. I believe that's as simple as having system B maintain a set of IP addresses that are allowed to call it and validating the IP address of each incoming call against this list. Is there a more structured or standard way to do this? What are the downsides of this approach? I'm thinking that having system B maintain a host name instead of an IP address and doing a reverse DNS lookup would protect against IP address changes for system A. Thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts: Reverse DNS is not reliable -- there's more issues managing DNS entries than IP address allocations.  IP mapping can be a problem if you need to account for different customers that might be accessing the service through a single server (i.e. web browser -> client server -> service)

Comment: Clarification: System B doesn't need to know the IP address of the end user. System B only needs to validate that the request is coming from system A (on behalf of the end user).

Comment: IP white listing is common in this case, if System A has a static IP.

Comment: One downside of "IP white listing" is that it might be hard to get at the source IP address using request.getRemoteAddr() if the request arrives at system B via intermediaries (load balancer, proxy server, etc.), in which case we could try request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR").

Comment: If the client is really not mobile, the forwarding proxy will also be static, and therefore you whitelist the proxy, not the host behind the proxy.

Comment: But then I'm potentially letting system C access system B because system C also happens to call system B via the same proxy. I only wish to allow system A access to system B.

Comment: Then perhaps IP whitelisting isn't as good an approach as API keys.

Answer (score 4):

The new (2018+) best practice would be to secure the internal services in exactly the same way that you'd secure external services.

Why?

Because upwards of 60% of data disclosures come from internal sources.  Internal systems are just as likely to breach data as external systems, so you need to have the same controls that you would for external systems.

Comment: This is some interesting data you present here. Do you have a source for these statistics? I would love to read more about this

Comment: https://securityintelligence.com/news/insider-threats-account-for-nearly-75-percent-of-security-breach-incidents/

Answer (score 2):

For starters, if both are in a private subnet, then already thats a decent amount of security. If you have any reason to believe outside people can connect to that API, then go ahead an implement a secure API key that is checked before any call is allowed to execute.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The subnet idea is interesting but I believe (as a downside) it leaves a gap with respect to unauthorized access from insiders. Regarding API keys, as the following presentation points out, the approach is apparently without standardization.

http://www.slideshare.net/jfaustin/securing-your-api

So far, I am in favor of (a) IP address mapping (easy, but fragile) or (b) SSL certificate based handshaking to allow system A to identify itself to system B (harder, but standardized and robust).

Comment: neither of those are particularly elegant. you really ought to just add credential authentication your API... i.e. in order to consume the API, make the consumer first call an authentication endpoint that will validate their credentials (proof they should be allowed to use it), which returns a temporary key, then all successive calls must provide that key, or die.